# How to get access to object's property?

Tags: javascript, object

I have very simple question about access a property of the object. The object is inside quotes.

For example:

```
var obj = '{"prop1": 4, "prop2":3}';
obj.prop1 --> //undefined
```

How can I remove quotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`obj` is a **string**. To convert it into an object, use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
var str = '{"prop1": 4, "prop2":3}';
var obj = JSON.parse(str);

obj.prop1; // 4
```